# How to select particuler column in core data?

Tags: ios, arrays, core-data

When the user has Pressed Login button i want to display the particular  first name  in alert view when the user has entered their username and password.
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.
Help will be appreciated.

```
    - (IBAction)LoginPressed:(id)sender
    { 


     if (managedObjContext == nil) {

    AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;


    managedObjContext= app.managedObjectContext;
}

NSFetchRequest *request =[[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];

NSEntityDescription *rocordTableEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"RecordTable" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjContext];


NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"username==% @AND password==%@",L_usernameField.text,L_passwordField.text];

NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstname=%@",[managedObjContext valueForKey:@"firstname"]];

[request setEntity:rocordTableEntity];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
[request setPredicate:pred];

NSError *error;

NSArray *arrarforCheckingUserANDPass = [managedObjContext executeFetchRequest:request       error:&error];
NSString *value =  [arrarforCheckingUserANDPass valueForKey:@"firstname"];



if (arrarforCheckingUserANDPass.count != 0) {




    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Welcome" message:value d elegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];

    [alert show];

}
else{

    NSLog(@"not matched");
}



}
```

Comment: Please copy/paste your *real* code. This one does not compile due to syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second `setPredicate` overwrites the first one. You do not need it. You get the whole entity and then simply access the `firstName` property. Your first predicate has wrong syntax.

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"RecordTable"];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
     @"username==%@ AND password==%@",L_usernameField.text,L_passwordField.text];

NSArray *result = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
RecordTable *user = result.firstObject;
if (user) {
   NSLog(@"The first name is %@.", user.firstName);
}
```

BTW, why does your method start with a capital letter? That is a very bad habit. Your entity name is also a disaster. "RecordTable" is about the worst entity name you could choose. If it is a user, call it "User". Following convention, I camel-cased your firstName property as well.

Comment: thanks for the help. but it just a practice project.